# can I boot ext4 usb stick with xubuntu on from a Mac laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, osx, ext4

is there a way to boot my `ext4` formatted "xubuntu" USB memory stick from a Mac laptop?

The laptop can identify `FAT32` usb memory sticks with ubuntu at boot time, but it cannot identify mine, which is `ext4`.

Is there a way to make Mac OS aware of ext4 partitions at boot time ?

Comment: Is there a bootloader on your memory stick?

Comment: yes there is grub.

Comment: Did you install it to the partition or to the MBR? Is the partition marked bootable?

Comment: it's in the MBR and it is marked bootable

Answer (score -1):

No sir, I have lot's  of experience on this thing and all I know that MS Fat have 4GB Limit and EXT4 do not but there is one exception about EXT4 that it can't be booted and Mac didn't detect it as booted.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure the question is about the ext4 Xubuntu volume not showing up in the bootloader. Not Mac OS being unable to mount the volume.